# Recorrer Query con foreach en laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent

Estimados tengo esta consulta sql y necesito que me entregue todos los datos de la tabla productos, pense que recorriendolo con foreach podia hacerlo pero solamente me esta entregando un solo producto y son 5. Creo que el error esta en que la variable $query no es un array..pero no me doy cuenta de como solucionarlo.

```
 $query1 = DB::table('productos as P1')
      ->select('C.idproducto')
      ->join('promoempresas as C', 'P1.id', '=', 'C.idproducto')
      ->where('C.codigo', $idpromo)
      ->groupBy('P1.id');
    $query2 =
      DB::table('productos as P2')
      ->select('CS.idproducto')
      ->join('promo_temp_products  as CS', 'P2.id', '=', 'CS.idproducto')
      ->groupBy('P2.id')
      ->union($query1)
      ->get();
    //return $query2;

    $data= json_decode($query2, true);
    //print_r($data);

    foreach($data as $key => $qs){

      //print_r($qs['idproducto']);
        $query =  DB::table('productos')
          ->where('id',$qs)
          ->get();
         return $query;


    }
```

Resultados:

```
0   
id  11
id_user 9
id_empresa  3
nombre  "Cajon de madera"
descripcion "Cajon de madera de mimbre"
imagen  "imagen"
id_umedida  "sin medicion"
id_categoria    "Sin categoira"
id_deposito "Stock de productos"
cantidad_ingreso    "123"
activo  "Producto activo"
precio  75.56
codigo  "u6dbb4sx"
dolar   "not_accepted"
peso    "accepted"
tasa_iva    0
eliminado   0
created_at  null
updated_at  null
```

Me deberia entregar 5 id, pero si lo recorro con print_r() los veo, si lo imprimo con echo tambien, pero necesito imprimirlo con JSON

Comment: es que tienes `return $query;` dentro del foreach, entonces solo hace la primer iteración y se sale de la función

Comment: Otra cosa. ¿Que te devuelve `print_r($data);`? tal vez con `whereIn()` puedas evitar hacer la query dentro de un loop.

Comment: Si saco el `return $query;` me devuelve el ultimo, pero con print_r($data); me devuelve todo el array completo con los 5 registros. No he probado whereIn()

Comment: Ok. Para seguir con tu idea de hacerlo dentro del foreach, tendría que declarar `$query = [];` antes del foreach y guardar el resultado de cada consulta en un índice de ese array `$query[] =  DB::table('...')`. Lo de [ `->whereIn('id', [1, 2, 3])`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#where-clauses) es porque con una sola consulta obtienes todos los datos.

Answer (score 2):

Gracias a `@porloscerros` la solucion estaba en utilizar `whereIn()`

```
  $query =  DB::table('productos')
          ->whereIn('id',$data)
          ->get();
        return $query;
```

Comment: Ah! genial! Mucho mejor práctica que hacer muchas consultas dentro de un loop